# Image Gallery in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to build a website using Orchard CMS. The site has a product listing page where it has to show multiple product images.  I would like to make a content type with Image Gallery to pick up multiple images for the product (has to show thumbnails too). Would this be possible? Can somebody direct me to the right documentation? The documentation on the Image Gallery codeplex site is not really well explained to my knowledge.  Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ImageMultipicker Field from Amba.ImagePowerTools module. 
It allows to pickup muliple images and has http://imageresizing.net/ library for resizing  under the hood.

https://imagepowertools.codeplex.com

https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Amba.ImagePowerTools/1.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a list for Products first. You can add Image Gallery widget to your list as a part.

Check this link for more information:
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-lists

Comment: Where can I find an image gallery widget?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be just what you're lookinghttp://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2012/03/30/zengallery-a-minimalist-image-gallery-for-orchard.aspx for: